# How to sort a linked list of Polynomials by degree?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

Currently I've written a method that adds two polynomials together. Poly1 and Poly2. The logic of the method is as follows, first it adds all matching degree terms from Poly1 and Poly2, then it adds all non-matching terms from Poly1, and finally adds all non-matching terms from Poly2. But because of this, the terms are out of order.

```
Polynomial answer = new Polynomial();

    for (Node firstPoly = poly; firstPoly != null; firstPoly = firstPoly.next){
        boolean polyAdded = false;
        for (Node secondPoly = p.poly; secondPoly != null; secondPoly = secondPoly.next){

            if (firstPoly.term.degree == secondPoly.term.degree){

            answer = addToRear(answer, (firstPoly.term.coeff + secondPoly.term.coeff), firstPoly.term.degree, null);
                    if (answer.poly.term.coeff == 0){
                        answer.poly = null;
                    }
                    polyAdded = true;           
            }


        }
        if (polyAdded == false){
        answer = addToRear(answer, firstPoly.term.coeff, firstPoly.term.degree, null);
        if (answer.poly.term.coeff == 0){
            answer.poly = null;
        }
        }

    }

    for (Node secondPoly = p.poly; secondPoly != null; secondPoly = secondPoly.next){
        boolean match = false;
        for (Node answerPoly = answer.poly; answerPoly != null; answerPoly = answerPoly.next){
            if (secondPoly.term.degree == answerPoly.term.degree){
                match = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (match == false){
        answer = addToRear(answer, secondPoly.term.coeff, secondPoly.term.degree, null);
        }
    }

    return answer;

    //alt + shift + r
}
```

If this code outputs:

8.0x^4 + 4.0x^5 + 2.0x^3 + -1.0x + 12.0

the linked list is represented as such:

(coefficient, degree) // (12, 0) -> (-1, 1) -> (2, 3) -> (4, 5) -> (8, 4)

I want to now sort my answer polynomial by order of degree. The linked list should be represented like this:

(coefficient, degree) // (12, 0) -> (-1, 1) -> (2, 3) -> (8, 4) -> (4, 5)

EDIT: Found the solution on my own. Here is the sorting method I created:

```
private Polynomial sortByDegree(Polynomial p){
    Node prev = p.poly;
    Node current = p.poly.next;

    while (current != null){
        if (current.term.degree < prev.term.degree){
            int temp = current.term.degree;
            current.term.degree = prev.term.degree;
            prev.term.degree = temp;

            float temp2 = current.term.coeff;
            current.term.coeff = prev.term.coeff;
            prev.term.coeff = temp2;

            prev = p.poly;
            current = p.poly.next;
        }

        prev = prev.next;
        current = current.next;
    }

    return p;
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I would need to know more about the definitions of your `Polynomial` and `Node` classes, but I suspect you are using an array or a `List` somewhere you should instead be using a `SortedSet`.

Comment: I've updated with the two requested classes. I have no freedom to modify these classes. Linked lists is what I am working with.

Comment: Indeed.  You are using a linked list structure for your `Polynomial` class.  I would suggest instead using a `SortedSet`, such as a `TreeSet`.

Comment: Like I said, I am unable to do this. I simply need to sort the Polynomial "answer" right before I return it, by degree.

This is for an assignment, and thus I have restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Can suggest two approaches:

First. Fetch linked list into array list (stack), sort array list, rebuild as linked list.

Second. Use following algo:

```
void sortPoly(Polynomial answer) {
    float lowerMargin = 0;
    Node head = null, tail = null;

    while (answer.poly != null) {
        Node next = detouchMin(lowerMargin, answer);
        lowerMargin = next.term.degree;

        if (tail != null) {
            tail.next = next;
            tail = next;
        else {
            head = next;
            tail = next;
        }
    }

    answer.poly = head;
}


Node detouchMin(float lowerMargin, Polynomial answer) {
    float min = Float.inf;
    Node n = null;
    Node t = answer.poly;
    while (t != null) {
        if ((t.term.degree > lowerMargin) && (t.term.degree < min)) {
            n = t;
            min = n.term.degree;
        }
        t = t.next;
    }

    if (n != null) {
        Node t = answer.poly, prev = null;
        while (t != null) {
            if (t == n) {
                if (prev != null)
                    answer.poly = t.next;
                else
                    prev.next = t.next;
            }
            prev = t;
            t = t.next;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

*Note: code not tested*

Comment: ... and yeah, it's an old, plain bubble-sort xD